# How to get seek time when zooming in/out using Wavesurfer?

Tags: video, wavesurfer.js

I am using [wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/timeline/index.html) library with Timeline plugin. And I am trying to get the time when a user clicks on the timeline.

Example of library and Timeline plugin:
https://codepen.io/lise26/pen/mpexma

Here is my current code thats works without the zoom(in/out) logic:

```js
this.player.on("seek", (postion) => {
  let videoDuration = 15; // in secs
  let zoomLevel = 100;
  let currentTime = postion * videoDuration;

  this.updateVideoCurrentTime(currentTime);
});
```

How can I get the time when a user clicks on the timeline while zooming in/out?

Comment: Your Codepen link's page doesn't do anything about drawing a waveform or playing audio. MP3 link was somehow SSL blocked to me so I tried a different MP3 URL and still got nothing (no sound, no waveform, no errors in console). Tested in Chrome/Windows... Just saying maybe it's better to show your own code that actually recreates your problem. For example your **actual issue here** could be recreated with just one `<div>` and also a mouse position listener on that div element. From there it **is just a maths problem**. Not obvious if zoom levels include a need to scroll (or it zooms centrally?)

Comment: @VC.One What I am looking for is really simple, when the user zoom in and he click on a time label, I want the the value of that time in seconds.